# Django Наследование не абстрактной модели и ptr

Tags: django

Есть юзер, который наследуется от абстрактной модели, который имеет некоторые поля:

```
@python_2_unicode_compatible
class User(AbstractUser):
    phone_number = models.ManyToManyField(PhoneNumber)    
    address = models.ForeignKey(Address, null=True)
    ...
```

Есть ещё один юзер, который ссылается на `User`.

```
class CustomProfile(models.Model):
    slug = models.CharField(null=True, max_length=255)
    user = AutoOneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, primary_key=True)
```

Задача состоит в том, чтобы CustomUser наследовал User, вот так:

```
class CustomProfile(User):
```

Но так как юзеры уже есть в базе данных есть, то при попытке создать миграцию, от меня требуется ввести дефолтный `user_ptr`. Так как это `primary_key`, то `null=True`, даже временно, не установить.

Как быть в ситуации? Что нужно указать по умолчанию?

Comment: А какой в этом смысл, чем не устраивает то, что есть сейчас?

Comment: Не устраивает то, что при необходимости создать  CustomProfile, нужно ссылаться на уже имеющегося юзера, либо, если речь идёт об django admin, нажать на "+".  Понимаю, что можно решить через форму, но по моему это не элегантный подход.

Answer (score 0):

Элегантно было бы переопределить самого пользователя, чтобы расширить.
Сами джанговцы рекомендуют использовать, как раз, отношение один-к-одному, как лёгкий способ.

Вы же хотите определить multi-table наследование.
Этот не способ не будет решать всех проблем. Так как будет всё-равно по умолчанию дефолтный пользователь.

Не умею работать с миграциями, нормально, поэтому сказанное ниже это предположение как сделать то, чего я никогда не делал:

1. Нужно переопределить поле для связи: `user = models.OneToOneField(DefaultUser, parent_link=True)`
2. Установить `default=None null=True`
3. Сделать миграции.
4. Пройтись скриптом для заполнения поля user.
5. Отключить `default=None null=True` и сделать миграции повторно.

Что получится, расскажите.